# How to process geo-referenced PDF files?

Tags: gdal

I need to process a batch of 3rd party PDF files to

- extract the bounding lat/long box
- convert them to a .mbtiles format

It looks like the gdal is the go to tool for this but non of the gdal command recognise my pdf as geo referenced. For instance:

```
gdalinfo 00989I11.PDF
ERROR 4: `00989I11.PDF' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '00989I11.PDF'.
```

I installed gdal 2.4.1 on macOS using `brew install gdal`
When I open the same PDF in Acrobat Reader, I can see the lat/long when moving my cursor:

You can [download the sample PDF file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nw82o89cjew3zl/00989I11.PDF?dl=0)
[image]

Comment: no it doesn't. Anything that can be from command line or via an API though as I will need to process hundreds of pdfs

Comment: Do you know what coordinate system it is?

Comment: it should be EPSG:4326

Answer (score 3):

On my Ubuntu box gdal 2.2.3 can read your PDF. Please check the supported formats:

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

There should be a line (among several ones):

```
PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
```

If no PDF support compiled into your gdal, you should look for another binary release or compile it from sources.

The projection is "Lambert conformal conic 2sp". I cannot find this projection in the EPSG file of proj. Here is the gdalinfo of your PDF:

```
Files: 00989I11.PDF
Size is 807, 1237
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS[,
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.000,298.25722210]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.000],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.000],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-120.64261111111102],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",35.23727777777781],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",45.00000000000001],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",33.00000000000001],
    UNIT["Inch",0.02540005080010]]
Origin = (-1807206.783370411256328,2042995.121725840726867)
Pixel Size = (3333.435032599861188,-3334.740105071813559)
Metadata:
  AUTHOR=
  CREATION_DATE=D:20190718071421-04'00'
  CREATOR=MicroStation 8.11.9.867 by Bentley Systems, Incorporated
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((-1487397.02629635 -1654170.76281271,563065.530890709 -16541
70.76282236,563065.530903317 1615087.4963082,-1487397.02636315 1615087.49628256,
-1487397.02629635 -1654170.76281271))
  PRODUCER=Adobe PDF Library 9.0
  TITLE=00989I11
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-1807206.783, 2042995.122) (121d 9' 6.33"W, 35d42'19.71"N)
Lower Left  (-1807206.783,-2082078.388) (121d 8'43.18"W, 34d45'28.84"N)
Upper Right (  882875.288, 2042995.122) (120d23'37.95"W, 35d42'22.90"N)
Lower Right (  882875.288,-2082078.388) (120d23'49.26"W, 34d45'31.98"N)
Center      ( -462165.748,  -19541.633) (120d46'19.17"W, 35d13'57.77"N)
Band 1 Block=807x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=807x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=807x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

QGIS can read and display it at the right position (but projection is marked as unknown), QGIS is based on gdal, so probably on your machine it won't work.

[image]

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I was trying. It looks like on macOS I need `brew install gdal2-pdf` from https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac. I'm compiling it now and will report back if that works. If that does not work, I'll install Ubuntu in a VM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question: I needed a version of gdal which supports pdf. On macOS it's [osgeo4mac](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac)

```
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew install gdal2-pdf
export GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gdalplugins
```

Then gdalinfo supports pdf:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep PDF
  PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
```

And the file from my original question can be inspected or converted to other formats:

```
gdalinfo 00989I11.PDF | grep -A 4 "Corner Coordinates:"
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-1807172.000, 2042985.000) (121d 9' 6.29"W, 35d42'19.70"N)
Lower Left  (-1807172.000,-2082410.000) (121d 8'43.15"W, 34d45'28.56"N)
Upper Right (  880032.000, 2042985.000) (120d23'40.84"W, 35d42'22.90"N)
Lower Right (  880032.000,-2082410.000) (120d23'52.11"W, 34d45'31.72"N)
```

Convert to tiff:

```
gdal_translate 00989I11.PDF 00989I11.tiff
    Input file size is 806, 1237
    0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Thanks @Zoltan for pointing me to the right direction